# X11 over remote Docker container stops working after resetting VPN

Tags: 18.04, ssh, xorg, docker, x11-forwarding

I'm running on ubuntu 18.04, with a "operator" machine VPN'ed into a network that has the "Test" machine.

The test machine runs a Docker container that has a GUI application that I forward over X11. I use SSH on the operator machine to SSH into the test machine. Then, I run the Docker container. Normally, the GUI shows up on my "operator" machine when I run the Docker container.

However, I've noticed that as soon as I disconnect my VPN and reconnect,I get a "Could not connect to display $DISPLAY" error.

I would need to create a new container from the image to have the X11 working again.

Here is how I launch it:

```
SOCK=/tmp/.X11-unix
XAUTH=/tmp/.docker.xauth
xauth nlist $DISPLAY | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -
chmod 777 $XAUTH
sudo docker run  --gpus all -it --privileged --network=host -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v $XSOCK:$XSOCK -v $XAUTH:$XAUTH -e XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH  image
```

Nothing changed on the "test" machine or docker container in this situation. Even if the VPN reconnect assigned me the same IP as prior, it would still have this issue.